# Cursor database query with WHERE

Tags: android, sqlite

My database query isnt working.
I'm trying to do a WHERE in the query but somehow it isnt working.
I want to get all the comentarios that have the same ISBN.

This is my DbHelper CLASS:

```
public static final String TABLE_LIVROS="livros";
public static final String KEY_AUTOR = "autor";
public static final String KEY_TITULO = "titulo";
public static final String KEY_ISBN = "isbn";
public static final String KEY_DATAPUBLICACAO = "dataPublicacao";

public static final String TABLE_COMENTARIOS ="tabelaComentarios";
public static final String KEY_TITULO_COMENT="tituloDoComentario";
public static final String KEY_PARTE_REFERENTE = "parteDoLivroReferente";
public static final String KEY_COMENTARIO = "comentario";
public static final String KEY_DATAPUB_COMENT = "dataPublicComentario";
public static final String KEY_LIVRO_REFERENTE = "livroReferente";
public static final String KEY_NUMERO_COMENT="1";


public static final String TABLE_LIVROS_CREATE = 
        "create table " + TABLE_LIVROS + " (" +
                KEY_ISBN + " integer primary key, " +
                KEY_TITULO + " text not null, " +
                KEY_AUTOR + " text not null, " + 
                KEY_DATAPUBLICACAO + " text not null);";

public static final String TABLE_COMENTARIOS_CREATE = 
        "create table" + TABLE_COMENTARIOS + " (" +
                KEY_NUMERO_COMENT + " integer primary key autoincrement, "+
                KEY_TITULO_COMENT + " text not null, " +
                KEY_PARTE_REFERENTE + " text not null, " +
                KEY_COMENTARIO + " text not null, " +
                KEY_DATAPUB_COMENT + " text not null, " +
                KEY_ISBN + " integer);" ; // FR KEY
```

The method i'm using to call the query is in the DbAdapter Class.

```
public Cursor getComentarios(String isbn){

        Cursor cursor;
         cursor = database.query(DbHelper.TABLE_COMENTARIOS, null, "isbn ="+isbn,
                 new String[] { isbn }, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
    }
```

Then i'm calling the Cursor in the See_comentario CLASS

```
private void displayList() {
        db.open();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ISBN: "+ isbn,              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try{    
        Cursor mCursor = db.getComentarios(isbn.trim());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cursor WORKS!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cursor DOESNT WORK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You are missing a space here: `"create table" + TABLE_COMENTARIOS` The table is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>ISBN is probably a string. Strings need to be wrapped by single-quotes.</strike>

This wrapping is done automatically by using placeholders ("?").

Try this:

```
 cursor = database.query(DbHelper.TABLE_COMENTARIOS, new String[] { KEY_TITULO },
         "isbn=?", new String[] { isbn }, null, null, null);
```

**Edit:**

I see that your ISBN is actually an integer, which is weird since ISBNs usually contain dashes.

Anyways the correct query would then be:

```
cursor = database.query(DbHelper.TABLE_COMENTARIOS, new String[] { KEY_TITULO },
        KEY_ISBN + "=" + isbn, null, null, null, null);
```

Note that you need to provide columns you want selected: `new String[] { KEY_TITULO }`.